# What is the mining pool's transaction choosing algorithm to maximize their reward?

Tags: mining-pools

I have read the Bitcoin Core(version 0.19)'s source code, I have read its transaction choosing algorighm, I found that algorithm can not maximize the minging reward，I think the mining pool has its own algorithm，so I want to know which algorighm does the mining pool use to choose transactions from transactioin pool to Maximize mining reward?
Is it knapsack algorithm？ or greedy algorithm？Is there someone can tell me? If you can show the source code, it would be even better. thanks a lot!

Comment: What makes you think it cannot maximize the reward?

Comment: There are many mining pools, each might be different.